# Identify numbers between special characters using regex python

Tags: python-3.x

```
Tried: 

Sentence = "Messers Buyer's Ref : LSM-021042-5 Payment : Port of Loading  and Ref : G2879G has applied with Ref : 031049 is also applied"
print(re.findall(r'(?:(?<=Ref : ))[\w\d-]+',text))
```

Is there any solution to answer 021042,G2879G,031049 by removing LSM and 5 from LSM-021042-5

Comment: So you don't just want to extract numbers but also combinations of numbers and letters such as `G2879G`?

Comment: @JanWilamowski Yes but if there is  reference like this  LSM-0210B2-5. I need to extract only 0210B2

Comment: How about simply `[\w\d]+`? (note that this will include underscores)

Comment: @JanWilamowski For LSM-021042-5 it will return as "LSM" only but I need 021042 as solution

Comment: @JanWilamowski Is there any solution??

Comment: It would be good to have a consistent pattern. E.g. does `Ref : ` always precede what you want to match?

Comment: you don't open duplicates because we're not fast enough for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69462205/how-to-extract-numbers-in-between-two-character-using-regex

Comment: Please be more specific in indicating the characteristics of the identifiers to be returned: letter and numbers, fixed length, prefixed and/or postfixed?